# switch $_GET variable else statement

Tags: php

I've runned into a problem. If it's possible, can i write an else statement for the $_GET['topic'] ?

```
case 'thread-view':
        if(isset($_GET['topic'])){
        $topicid = $_GET['topic'];

        $psql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE th_p_link='$topicid' ORDER BY p_id ASC";
        $presult = mysqli_query($db,$psql);
        while($prow = mysqli_fetch_array($presult)){

            $post = $prow['p_post'];
            $author = $prow['p_author'];
            $avatar = $prow['p_avatar'];
            $gm = $prow['p_gm'];
            $date = $prow['p_date'];
            $link = $prow['th_p_link'];

        echo '
        <div class="post_box">
            <div id="post-left">
                <img src="'.$avatar.'" alt="">
                <div id="post-about">
                    <span>'.$author.'</span>
                    <span>Member</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="post-content">
            <p>'.htmlspecialchars($post, ENT_QUOTES).'</p>
            </div>
            <div id="post-right">
            <i>'.$date.'</i>
            </div>
        </div>
        ';
        }
        }
    break;

    default:
    include 'template/forum_categories.php';
```

For an example, if i go to the URL

> forums.php?page=thread-view&topic=testurlpost

It shows the page correctly. Though what i'm trying to achieve is that if i go to something that doesn't exist such as

> forums.php?page=thread-view&topic=testurlthatdoesntexist

I want it to re-direct to another page, such as an error page. How would i achieve this? I made an else statement for the $_GET['topic'] but that did not work when i entered the non-existing URL.

Comment: `/forums.php?topic=';%20DROP%20TABLE%20posts;%20--`

Comment: Was there an error and that's why it didn't work? Did you check your error log?

Comment: After your query, check for result rows if there are zero rows, than the id didnt exists, so you can use `header('Location:xy.php');exit;` to redirect

Comment: your also completely open to sql injection, suppose the `$_GET['topic'] ` is = to something like this `"'; SELECT * FROM posts WHERE 1--"` or worse  `"'; DROP TABLE posts --"`  I would suggest rewriting the query using prepared statements...  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thanks for letting me know. I never knew that. So, for the $_GET, i should use the prepared statements. Can i use mysqli_real_escape_string for $_POST variables?

Comment: @Synyster - I would use them anytime you input anything into a query, you never know when you may re-use a bit of code and what was once non-user input becomes user input..  Also it doesn't hurt to use them everywhere.  I would avoid `mysqli_real_escape_string` and instead write the queries like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=?` then use `mysqli->prepare()` etc. as done on this page http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: The difference from using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and a prepared statement is that `mysqli_real_escape_string` only escapes the data and prepared statements separate when it is executed against the database, basically the query is evaluated during prepare, and then the variables are added in a second stage.  This two part behavior lets the database know not to interpret the variables as possible SQL commands.  That then makes SQL Injection attacks practically impossible, when used correctly.

Comment: The reason sql injections work is take your query `"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE th_p_link='$topicid' ORDER BY p_id ASC"` and add what I put in place of  your input, `"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE th_p_link=''; DROP TABLE posts --' ORDER BY p_id ASC"`  Everything after the `--` is a comment in sql.  So what It does is complete the first query `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE th_p_link='';` and allow a second query ( of my choosing ) `DROP TABLE posts` to be executed.  This could be destroying your data, or even creating a new DB user.  Escaping it just changes that first single quote `\'` in  the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
   if(!mysqli_num_rows($presult)) {
       header("Location: /error-page.html");
    }
```

before While statement. So your code will look something like this:

```
case 'thread-view':
    if(isset($_GET['topic'])){
    $topicid = $_GET['topic'];

    $psql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE th_p_link='$topicid' ORDER BY p_id ASC";
    $presult = mysqli_query($db,$psql);

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($presult)) {
       header("Location: /error-page.html");
    }

    while($prow = mysqli_fetch_array($presult)){
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about the mysqli_num_rows function